# Why does Samsung Android browser say our site has a valid certificate, but the site identity has not been verified?

Tags: tls, certificates, android, letsencrypt

Our website using Let's Encrypt through Nginx is all green on [SSLLabs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ekaya.vip&hideResults=on) (A- score).

But on one Android phone it accepts the certificate and sees the trust chain up to the root certifying authority, but still says the site isn't fully trusted:

[image: Picture of a popup saying "ekaya.vip" The identity of this website has not been verified. etc.]

here's the certificate info:

[image: Information of the certificated used by the "ekaya.vip" website]

**How do we fix this?**

---

Partial quote of the text in the first image:

> The identity of this website has not been verified. The identity of
>   the server to which you are connected cannot be fully validated. You
>   are connected to a server using a name valid only within your network,
>   and an external certificate authority has no way to validate
>   ownership.

Browser is Samsung 'Internet' version 3.5.38

Comment: It may be that the cert is valid in terms of Common Name (domain), but it can't be verified due to revocation, broken validation chain (lack of intermediate certs on new SHA-2 certs), expired or anything  else preventing  it to be fully valid. I'd bet for the intermediate certs which is the case in 2016 since the upgrade to SHA-2.

Comment: But the ssllabs link above shows no chain issues, and no expiry problems. I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do anything about it but to upgrade your Android.

The problem here is a generic top-level domain `.vip` and older Android versions do not recognise them as public (hence the "a name valid only within your network" message). It's a known problem and Wikipedia lists it as one of the [technical issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain#Technical_issues) with these domains.

With Internet app version 4.0 on Android Marshmallow, your certificate is verified properly.

---

<sup>The Internet application is a component of Android, so it's not Samsung, but Google.</sup>